# webrtc2sip configuration without sipml5

Tags: webrtc, ims

How can i connect my webrtc2sip gateway to my p-cscf without sipml5. I want to configure the ip address and port number of my p-cscf directly from webrtc2sip.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Webrtc2sip is based on [RFC 7118](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7118). This means that the SIP signaling have to be routed via websocket using the rules in this RFC and then the webrtc2sip gateway will be able to handle it.

Comment: i want to configure the address and port of my p-cscf from webrtc2sip server not from the sipml5 client. I didn´t get